# C shell script - if loop with grep expression

Tags: csh, tcsh

I have the below code where I need to grep this word "Build of target" in build.log if exists then I need to execute another script which I have included in it as shown below.

```
#!/tool/aticad/1.0/bin/tcsh -f
if (grep -q "Build of target : PASS" build.log) then
source sh.csh
else
echo "fail"
endif
```

Then I did source script.csh. But above code is failing due to this:

```
if: Expression Syntax.
```

May I know why I am getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`** (back-quote) to assign an output from a system command.

And, `grep` returns `0` if the match is found, and `1` if it's not. You can test this by running the specific regex and print the output with `echo $?`

So the correct syntax is;

```
#!/bin/csh -f
if (`grep -q "Build of target : PASS" build.log`) then
    echo "Not found - grep returns 1"
else
    echo "Found - grep returns 0"
endif
```

Comment: still same if: Expression Syntax.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/tool/aticad/1.0/bin/tcsh -f 
if (grep -q "Build of target : PASS" build.log);then 
     source sh.csh 
else 
      echo "fail" 
fi
```

This is the code for bash script. Create the script and run it.

Comment: if the above script is for bash script then we need to change interpreter to #!/bib/bash. Anyways I tried the above script goutham but facing this issue if: Expression Syntax.
then: Command not found.

Comment: I don't have the log file so I cannot try it. I just pointed out the errors. And I forgot about the #/bib/bash . Sorry